# Test freeSolo input pattern with MUI Autocomplete + React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using an `AutoComplete` component with React Hook Form. My AutoComplete has `freeSolo` and `multiple`.

But I'm unable to test the pattern of the input in my `TextField`. I would like the input to follow a specific pattern and to see my field in an error state when the input doesn't match the pattern ( and more important to prevent adding the value with `freeSolo` in this case ). How can I reach such a result, especially without having to override `onChange` / `onInputChange` ? Here is my component:

```
                  <Controller
                    defaultValue={[]}
                    control={control}
                    name='versions'
                    rules={{
                      required: true,
                      pattern: { // Doesnt work...
                        value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$/,
                        message: 'Only . - are accepted as special characters.'
                      }
                    }}
                    render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
                        <Autocomplete
                          {...field}
                          freeSolo
                          multiple
                          autoSelect
                          onChange={(event, item) => {
                            onChange(item)
                          }}
                          options={[]}
                          value={value || []}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              label="Version(s)"
                              margin="normal"
                              variant="standard"
                              inputProps={{
                                ...params.inputProps,
                                required: value.length === 0,
                                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$/ // Doesnt work neither
                              }}
                              error={!!errors.versions}
                              required
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                    )}
                  />
```

Thanks in advance !